# Associating buttons with an index

Tags: forms

I have a form with a set of radios. Each radio should have a corresponding button that 'deletes' the radio:

Radio1
    --delete button 1
  Radio2
    --delete button 2
  ...

How do I pass along index information when I click on a button? Buttons do not have convenient indexed values like the radios so I can't do something like

`$index = $form_state['triggering_element']['values']`

The only method that works at the moment is comparing the #id of the delete button one by one with `$form` until I find a match. What is a better way of going about this?

Comment: plz elaborate it further, for example once i had fixed number of radios (3) and i had to do same thing, i simply inserted three forms each having a radio button and a submit button, each radio was associated with a node so in submit function i deleted the node, if you too have some fixed number of radios less than say 5, you can consider this. having large number of radios can cause performance issues with this solution